# Is there any way to insert batch (bulk) of records in BigCommerce in single API call using c#

Tags: c#, bigcommerce

In my application I have used BigCommerce rest avi v2. I need to insert over 2000 records to BigCommerce. The method I am using, takes more than a hour for this. It makes new API call for every row, hence it is taking that much time. So I want to know that if there is any method available which would take data in a batch and insert in a single API call?

Comment: If you use a foreach and call the `insert()` method for each item, and then call `savechanges()` after the loop, it should be pretty quick.

Comment: I am using BigCommerce rest API to insert my data on BigCommerce server. BigCommerce provides it own API for this. The issue is that the API I am using can take only one data row at a time so it is taking too much time to insert when there is big number of records. I am asking for any method that would take records in batch.

Comment: You have to do them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is not possible using the current API. The only method available is to loop through your results and issue single API calls for each record.

According to the [API documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started), all of the create and update methods of the BigCommerce API only handle a single record